# Windows backup in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, windows-7

I am trying to copy the c:\Users folder from a Windows 7 Installation for a backup under Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD.  The file transfer seems to be calculating way more info than there actually is in the folder.  I am assuming this is do to the "shortcuts" in Windows.  It seems to want to copy every shortcut as an full fledged directory.  Is there some other way of doing this easily? Drag in drop in Nautilus?

Comment: Proabably it's the hidden files and folders which are taking a lot of space.

Answer (score 0):

Selective copying would be easier in that you only copy folders such as Documents, Movies, Photos etc. over to your Ubuntu partition...  Windows will see shortcuts as a small link file whereas Ubuntu/Linux has it's own method called symbolic links so it may treat Windows' links as a complete directory in itself...